# Inner product between vectors in z direction of a tensors

Tags: matlab

**Initializations:**

```
  a = [1 2]'; 
  z1 = [1 2 3;4 5 6]; 
  z2 = [7 8 9;10 11 12];
  z = cat(3,z1,z2);
  e = repmat(permute(a, [2 3 1 ] ),2,3);
```

**Derided result:**

Find `2x3` matrix `t` whose elements are `t(1,1) = inner product between z(1,1,:) and e(1,1,:)`, `t(2,2) = inner product between z(2,2,:) and e(2,2,:), etc.`

Comment: Can you provide the output for and example `z`?

Comment: I'm assuming you want `t(1,1)` to be `squeeze(z(1,1,:))'*squeeze(e(1,1,:))` and `t(1,2)` = `squeeze(z(1,2,:))'*squeeze(e(1,2,:))` etc...?

Comment: I have reformulate the question to have all specific result.

Comment: Are you sure about your new `z`? It has different dimensions from before. because now `z(1,1,:)` has 2 elements where `e(1,1,:)` has 4... so what product were you looking for there? Also please provide a numerical worked example `t`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change `a`.

Comment: We still need a worked example... I'm fairly confident about my solution to be honest so if it's not right it would help to see what you're expecting so I can tweak it. My solution yields `t = [15, 18,  21; 24, 27, 30]` for your current set of parameters

Comment: I think they are correct and alternatively you can do it by: `t= sum(e.*z,3);`

Comment: you will have to test it but `bsxfun` is normally more efficient than `repmat`. If my answer is correct then please accept it, other post your own answer and accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
t = permute(sum(bsxfun(@times, a, permute(z, [3 1 2]))), [2, 3, 1])
```

notice I've used `a` rather than `e` as `bsxfun` makes the `repmat` uneccesary

now `t(1,1)` equals the inner product of `z(1,1,:)` and `e(1,1,:)`, `t(1,2)` equals the inner product of `z(1,2,:)` and `e(1,2,:)` etc...